# как при нажати кнопки в Android Studio открыть браузер с введеным текстом в строку поиска

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался браузер с текстом введенным в строку поиска в Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите активити с указанием адреса в сети [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4800679/3212712):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"))))
```